# How can i print this in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I print the attached pattern in Python?

Am a beginner and am trying to learn Python. Please help

If you cant see the pattern then please see the comments section.

```
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```

Comment: *******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******

Comment: We get many homework questions like this: show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @John1024 I tried doing it the manual way with this print("*" * 7 )

Comment: @John1024 but i want to learn the short way of doing it. Can you help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. While you may have good intentions, currently your question has a form which is discouraged by most of users and usually does not result in receiving valuable answers. I'll recommend getting familiar with [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can loop through like follows.

```
number_of_rows = 5
value_range = range(0, number_of_rows)
middle_value = number_of_raws / 2
for i in value_range:
    if i < middle_value:
        print('*'*(number_of_rows-middle_value-i))
    else:
        print('*'*(i-middle_value+1))
```

Here `number_of_rows` defines the number of lines you need to use to draw this "K" like pattern.